# Ajax POST and Django Tastypie

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, tastypie

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"latlong": "test"}' http://localhost:8000/geo/api/geolocation/
```

The above works fine but when I try to replicate the POST in the ajax below I get 500 error.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/geo/api/geolocation/',
  data: '{"latlong": "test"}',
  success: latlongSaved(),
  dataType: "application/json",
  processData:  false,
});
```

Error message is:

```
{"error_message": "The format indicated 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' had no available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`` on your Serializer." .... }
```

Worth noting this is cross domain and I'm using the django-crossdomainxhr-middleware.py found via git:gist

If I add a content type to the ajax call like this:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

I get this error back:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/geo/api/geolocation/. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/geo/api/geolocation/
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Access-Control-Request-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 23 Aug 2011 07:59:49 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.1
```

Comment: Check the docs - you may need to set the json option in the url string.

Comment: Can you post the diff between the `curl` request headers and the jQuery headers?  You can see the jQuery headers in the console tab inside Firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS to the middleware and that solved the problem.

https://gist.github.com/1164697

Answer (score 7):

You are explicitly declaring your content type in your call to `curl`, but you are not being specific on your [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.

Update your JavaScript to define exactly what the content type is going to be:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/geo/api/geolocation/',
  data: '{"latlong": "test"}',
  success: latlongSaved(),
  dataType: "application/json",
  processData:  false,
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Just for clarity could you mention what `dataType` does?

Comment: You're doing cross domain AJAX calls. That won't work for JSON, you must use JSONP

Comment: `dataType` tells jQuery what type of data you are expecting the server to return.

Answer (score 3):

Add XsSharing (https://gist.github.com/1164697) to settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...,
    'django-crossdomainxhr-middleware.XsSharing'
]
```

Then use the following javascript to make an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/geo/api/geolocation/',
  data: '{"latlong": "test"}',
  success: latlongSaved(),
  contentType:'application/json',
  dataType: 'application/json',
  processData: false,
});
```

Notice that `data` must be a well-formed JSON string, otherwise jQuery will silently ignore the ajax call and do nothing.

What's behind the scenes is that the ajax call will firstly send out `OPTIONS /geo/api/geolocation/`. Because the response header is modified by XsSharing middleware, jQuery will issue another `POST /geo/api/geolocation` request that does the actual creation.

Comment: This: "Notice that data must be a well-formed JSON string, otherwise jQuery will silently ignore the ajax call and do nothing", helped me a lot! Thanks